# Navigating Dynamically created Pages

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm having a little issue navigating to dynamically created pages (with C# & XAML (visual studio 2015 edition).
I can create the pages (I assume), but when I navigate to them it gives me the original page.

I guess it might be to do with the GetType of test/test2 which is pointing to the Dynamic_Page_1 page (this page has nothing on it), but how do I go about forcing it to use the new instance which I'm modifying?

```
            // Dynamic Page One
            Dynamic_Page_1 test = new Dynamic_Page_1();
            Button b = new Button { Content = "DYNAMIC TEST ONE", FontSize = 22, FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold };
            test.Stack().Children.Add(b);

            // Dynamic Page Two
            Dynamic_Page_1 test2 = new Dynamic_Page_1();
            TextBlock t1 = new TextBlock {Text = "DYNAMIC TEST TWO" };
            test2.Stack().Children.Add(t1);

            // Dynamically create buttons which link to both Dynamically created pages
            Button b3 = new Button { Content = "GO TO TEST ONE", };
            Button b4 = new Button { Content = "GO TO TEST TWO", };

            b3.Click += (s, e) => {
                Frame.Navigate(test.GetType());
            };
            b4.Click += (s, e) =>
            {
                Frame.Navigate(test2.GetType());
            };

            stackPanel1.Children.Add(b3);
            stackPanel1.Children.Add(b4);
```

Comment: Stack() is just the public property for stackPanel which lives on the Dynamic_Page_1

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this in the end by passing through the stackpanel.

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Dynamic_Page_1), stackPanel1);
```

Then modifying the navigateTo part to look for it.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel stack = (StackPanel) e.Parameter;
    // Do something with stackpanel.
}
```